# Are fonts blocking?

Tags: html, google-font-api

When I run

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

in the `<head>`

is it blocking the page while the font downloads?

Here is a pic , but I see no mention of the font or my favicon for that matter.

[image]

Comment: Did you check the browser's dev tools to see?

Comment: I'm using Google dev tools, and I find it unreadable as it makes the individual resources 1px height, and has a color code that it does not define any where that I am aware of, thought I guess like everything it is on the web.  I'll post a pic ...

Comment: I see it under fonts but I can't locate it on the time line.

Comment: Make sure to click settings (F1) in developer tools and click "Disable cache" to make sure it doesn't use the cached version. 

You also have "XHR" selected in the image. You'll want to select "CSS" and reload.

Comment: select fonts actually.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. CSS can be render blocking too: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

Google & Typekit offer a JS library to asynchronously load fonts:
https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/webfont_loader

GitHub / direct link: https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

Note that asynchronously loading font CSS can cause FOUT (Flash of Unstyled Text), a momentary delay where the type is displayed in its basic font before your styled font is loaded.

If you use this library, it should give any text waiting to be styled a class of "wf-loading" that you can then handle through basic CSS. For example, you can just do `.wf-loading {display: none}` and any text waiting to be styled simply won't be displayed until it's been styled.

Comment: Wikipedia has this problem of FOUT

Answer (score 0):

You won't see fonts in the `xhr` tab in dev tools. Click the `font` tab. Or better yet, click `font` then Ctrl+Click the `css` tab to see both. You also won't see favicon in the network tab and [that's by design](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=260195).

Font files load async (not render blocking). So putting `@font-face` directly in your `<head />` won't necessarily prevent a FOUT. The DOM will continue to render while the HTTP request for those font files (ex woff2, ttf, etc) is running async.

CSS is render blocking, and usually the css file(s) on a site will take longer to download and parse so your font files are available before the CSS is done painting. If you try to load the site without any CSS you'll probably see this FOUT.